# Question about deploying a JRuby script

Tags: java, deployment, jruby

I'm looking to replace MRI with JRuby for some scripts. Would it be enough to provide an ant buildfile and the JRuby jar for them? Would something else be needed ( beside the JDK of course )?

EDIT: when I'm saying *"the JRuby jar"*, I'm meaning **jruby-complete.jar**.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You don't need to do anything except execute with jruby instead of ruby.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was trying to do. I succeeded. Add an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Remember that on stackoverflow it's ok to answer your own question, if you found an answer that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the JDK ( and the gems required by the application ) nothing else is required. JRuby complete has everything one needs.